# How do I add pages to menu?

Tags: magento, menu, content-management-system

I am new to Magento; now I am trying to develop a simple example site.
                                                                                                        My question is this: how can we add pages to main menu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the official Magento recommendation on how to do this: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/adding-page-links-in-the-navigation-bar

To add a CMS page link to top navigation the hard way, you should override `/mnt/www/x1886/app/design/frontend/default/default/template/catalog/navigation/top.phtml`.

There are plenty tutorials out there about how to override files in Magento.

Change a change where I placed a comment:

```
<div class="header-nav-container">
    <div class="header-nav">
        <h4 class="no-display"><?php echo $this->__('Category Navigation:') ?></h4>
        <ul id="nav">

        <!-- ADD ADDITIONAL LINKS HERE -->

        <?php foreach ($this->getStoreCategories() as $_category): ?>
            <?php echo $this->drawItem($_category) ?>
        <?php endforeach ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topLeftLinks') ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Internet Wayback Machine URL to the broken Magento Knowledge Base link: http://web.archive.org/web/20141217193408/http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/adding-page-links-in-the-navigation-bar

Answer (score 6):

create one static block with "Your page name"
Create new category with display mode "Static block only" and "include in navigation menu = YES"  and select your cms block and save category. And see in front-end side this will be added in navigation item.

Comment: Whilst it's true this works and is easy, be aware that this only adds a static block to the catalog page.  To add a static PAGE to the main nav, this needs to be done using redirection, details of which can be found all over the web.